# Having a single div in a row with the others?

Tags: css, html

I've read a bunch of SO questions/answers on side-by-side (row) divs, but I don't think I'm grasping it as I can't find a solution for my specific setup:

http://www.trforums.com/h18-iwaku

Basically, I want the div on the very bottom to be to the right to the "Hey, What's up", "Navigation," and "Connect" boxes, instead of just under them. Is this possible to do?

The divs themselves are just classes with their corresponding html content. It's very basic but here's my code:

http://pastebin.com/AQrqqewA

My html is very rusty so other suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding each column in a DIV:

```
<!-- Left column -->
<div id="leftColumn">
    <div class="ex">
        <center><img style="display: inline;" src="http://i.imgur.com/wCP3WP3" alt="" /></center>
        <h1>Hey, what's up?</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
        <b>NAVIGATION:</b> <a href="http://joshpho.weebly.com/zukan.html">Zukan</a> | <a href="http://joshpho.weebly.com/movies.html">Movies</a> | <a href="http://joshpho.weebly.com/retsuden.html">Retsuden</a>  | <a href="http://joshpho.weebly.com/misc.html">Photography</a> |
        </div>

    <div class="connect">
        <b>CONNECT:</b> <a href="http://joshpho.livejournal.com/profile">Livejournal</a> 
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Right column -->
<div id="rightColumn">
    <div class="slideshow">
        Bottom div that I want in a row with the top one...
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 410px; // Width of this column
}

#rightColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 500px; // Width od this column
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. So would we just using margins to fix the overlap/height difference? (http://www.trforums.com/h18-iwaku)

Comment: You have to fix the margins in the classes: `ex` and `slideshow` because they are breaking the style. Try removing them and see what happends.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `div` with a class `slideshow` next to the `div` with a class `ex` and apply floats, as you can see in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/odugug/3/edit)

The final result can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/odugug/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` or `display:inline` on the divs that you want next to each other.

Comment: But then I'd have to do it to all four of the divs which would make all of them in a row. I want the first three to be in a column and then the fourth one to be to the right of the rest of them.

Comment: Add a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` between two DIVs to interrupt the floating